# Change background color of column with facetted ggplot in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I've created a shiny app with a ggplot output that can be facetted, which creates whitespace on top of the background color of the column. You can see it happening here. What I would like to do is have the whitespace be the same color as the background color indicated in the UI code. [image: Here]

In my UI, I'm using the following code to change the background color:

```
column(9,
       style = "background-color: blue;",
       align = "center",
       ...
       )
```

Comment: You can style any app element (id, div, class etc.) using css. Create css file and put there styling rules. If you provide full shiny app code, I will show you how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `"background-fill"` instead of `"background-color"`? R differentiates between the outline and the contents, these are called "color" and "fill" respectively.